# How to compare item name of two listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried compare mached and not mached items count and items name of two listboxes.

I want to display Mached Items Name in `listMachedItems`,Mached Items Count in `lblMachedItemsCount`.

And display NotMached Items Name in `listNotMachedItems`,NotMached Items Count in `lblNotMachedItemsCount`.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items[i] == listBox2.Items[j])
        {
            y++;

            //found mached items
            //lblMachedItemsCount.Text = y.ToString() + " " + "items are mached";
            // listMachedItems.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());

             break;

          }
          else
          {
               x++;
               //lblNotMachedItemsCount.Text = x.ToString() + " " + "items are not mached";
               // listNotMachedItems.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
               break;
           }
      }   
 }
```

Comment: Could you please delete unnecessary empty lines in your code?

Answer (score 3):

```
listMachedItems.ItemsSource = listBox1.Items.Where(x => listBox2.Items.Contains(x));
listNotMachedItems.ItemsSource = listBox1.Items.Where(x => !listBox2.Items.Contains(x));
lblNotMachedItemsCount.Text = listNotMachedItems.Count() + " items are not matched";
lblMachedItemsCount.Text = listMachedItems.Count() + " items are matched";
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'ItemsSource' and no extension method 'ItemsSource' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3):

```
listMatchedItems.Items.AddRange(list1.Intersect(list2).ToArray());
listMachedItemsCount = listMatchedItems.Count();

listNotMatchedItems.Items.AddRange(list1.Except(list2).ToArray());
listNotMachedItemsCount = listNotMatchedItems.Count();
```

Comment: I can not see ItemsSource ,Intersect,Except.I used "using System.Windows.Forms;"

Answer (score 0):

```
     var list1 = Enumerable.Intersect(listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray(), listBox2.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
       for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
       {
           if (list1.Contains(listBox1.Items[i]))
           {


               listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);

               listMatchedItems.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]).ToString();
           }

           else

           {

               listNotMatchedItems.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]).ToString();
           }


       }

    var list2 = Enumerable.Intersect(listBox2.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray(), listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
       for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
       {
           if (list2.Contains(listBox2.Items[i]))
           {
               int a = i + 1;
               listBox2.SetSelected(i, true);


           }
           else
           {


           }

           }
```